# How can the rate of Mana output from mages reach a state of equilibrium during a spell?

Tags: magic, energy, power-sources

Witches and warlocks have been working together for centuries. Witches have ley lines running throughout their circulatory system, in which their Mana flows through. These ley lines give them the ability to channel their Mana into magical spells. Warlocks in contrast have no ley lines, and are therefore unable to perform magic. However, this fact allows them to be excellent receptacles for containing magical energy. These opposing gifts allow the two to work in tandem when performing Wicca magic.

During a ritual, a group of seven witches position themselves around a Wicca circle, with the warlock standing within the center. The witches pool their mana into the warlock all at once, turning him into a conduit for their magical energy. This is done while reciting incantations, and can take anywhere from minutes to hours depending on the spell. Whole this can produce powerful magic, it can be dangerous when done incorrectly.

As the warlock has no ley lines to hold magic, the Mana is constantly seeping out of him during the spell. The flow of magic from the witches must be constant and at a quick enough pace to for it to outpace the leakage in order to be of any use. Much of this has to be intuitive, as the incantation cannot break while being performed. However, there are limits to how much power the warlock can contain. If too much Mana is pushed out to him at a pace faster than he can receive, it will overload his form and explode with magical energy.

The witches need to match pace with each other in their output of Mana, at a high enough rate for it to be effective, all without killing the warlock at the center. How can they coordinate their efforts in this way?

Comment: Perhaps a lizard amulet of mana equilibrium would suffice? As written this reads more like an idea generation question where any opinion is going to be equally valid.

Comment: Notation: Ley lines are lines between geographical locations (original roads between British villages, most of whose names ended in "ley", hence the name). This has been extended in common usage to be lines of power in the Earth. Your witches should have something else, maybe nerve lines or mana conductors.

Comment: Also, not a good idea to use the name of a real world religion (Wicca) in a story like this.

Comment: Can you clarify a couple of things.
Why can't the witches do the whole spell? Why need the warlock?
Can the warlock control the output of power? Like if it is too much he can simply turn some of that power into something like so not die?
What type of control does the warlock has?
Do all spells have this explosion side effect?
Do they have to channel their full power into him?
Can they create a double effect spell with an error detection system?
Like the warlock's head is surrounded by a green aura if everything is going well,changes to other colors to match what is happening?

Answer (score 2):

## Group dance

In the class works of nerd magic (therefore: Dungeons and Dragons and GURPS, not the Key of Solomon nor the Hermetic Corpus), [spells have three components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_in_Dungeons_%26_Dragons#Components):

1. A verbal one
2. A somatic one
3. A material one

You have your verbal one in:

> This is done while reciting incantations

And the material one in:

> The witches pool their mana into the warlock all at once

The somatic one may be interpretative dance. Just singing - sorry, reciting incantations would be nice to match everybody's pace and mana flow, but there is always the oddball who refuses to train with a metronome and who will be singing slightly off tempo. But when you add group dance to it, everybody has a visual clue on what move they should do next. It really helps get everybody in synchronized motion, so their ley lines will also be in sync.

Here is a group of witches using dance instead of incantations in order to cast an expulsion spell at a former member of their coven: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QIrbN23yUkA&t=13

Answer (score 1):

You've forgotten the burnt offering component of the spell.

Seven witches surround a man who serves as a vessel for their magic.

In his arms, he clutches an animal.

The size of the animal varies depending on the power level of the spell.
During the final stage of the casting, as the power reaches sufficient levels to achieve the goal, the man utters the final words of power, completing the witches' incantation.
Power rushes from him, out into the world to accomplish the spell's purpose.

Any power which is left behind, or any which feeds back into the circle after the spell is done, spills into the animal, incinerating it while leaving the witches and warlock unharmed.

If there is not enough excess energy left to completely incinerate the poor beast, a ceremonial dagger can be used to put the poor half-burnt creature out of its misery.